# how to add equal empty spaces between images

Tags: html, css

[image: Example image of my code]

i want to do this in html , there is a div outter of images .
html;

```
<div class="posts-thumbnails">
                        <img src="img/archive1.png">
                        <img src="img/archive1.png">
                        <img src="img/archive1.png">
                        <img src="img/archive1.png">
                        <img src="img/archive1.png">
                        <img src="img/archive1.png">
</div>
```

css;

```
.posts-thumbnails img{
width:100px;
height:100px;
margin:10px;
}
```

But i couldn't manage images margin or padding , if i write something like this , images have 10+10 20 empty space , how can i add equal empty spaces between images

Comment: Are you floating the images? Also, will there always be 3 images per row or is the number flexible?

Comment: You can add the margin to specific images, like the 2nd and 5th images.

Comment: I'm sure there will be an existing answer somewhere. One simple method is to apply the right and bottom margins on the images and then the top and left spacing with a padding on the container. [Like this example](http://jsbin.com/qajaqi/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: misterManSam , thanx , this is my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, as the comments to your question have already pointed out, there is a lot we don't know about what you want to do and how you want it to look in the end (float, number of images, positioning, width for the containing div), but if it's really just the margin you're asking about, this answer might be enough.

Simply go with

```
.posts-thumbnails img{
width:100px;
height:100px;
margin:5px;
}
```

to style your div.

Here's what it looks like (jsfiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/manroo9c/

It works by adding only 5px of margin around every image. Since the margin on the right of an image is of 5 and on the left of the image right up next is also 5, in the end the space between them will be one of 10px. This is also the case for the space between images standing one on top of the other.

**UPDATE:** This *will* get you 5px of margin from the image to the border of the containing div in any direction, though, so if you also want 10px distance from images to border here's an updated jsfiddle with 5px padding on the containing div: http://jsfiddle.net/manroo9c/1/

Here's the CSS code:

```
.posts-thumbnails img{
width:100px;
height:100px;
margin:5px;
}

.posts-thumbnails{
padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: thank you for great answer , this can be very useful for understanding of margins and paddings

Answer (score 1):

Here is your simple solution http://jsbin.com/higidaboqe/1/edit?html,css,output
just add float and only right & bottom padding or margin.

Comment: Yes , this can be also useful

Answer (score 0):

Is this is what you want to do??? JS FIDDLE -> https://jsfiddle.net/JTcGZ/1156/

```
 <div id="blah">
        <a id="image1" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
        <a id="image2" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
        <a id="image3" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
        <span class="stretch"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="blah">
        <a id="image1" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
        <a id="image2" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
        <a id="image3" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
        <span class="stretch"></span>
    </div>


    #blah {   
        width: 540px;
        margin-top:20px;
        margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right: auto;

         text-align: justify;
        -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
        text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    }
    #blah a {
        vertical-align: top;
        display: inline-block;
        *display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
    }
    .stretch {
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 0;
        line-height: 0
    }
```

Comment: Hey bro , it is okay but , i dont want to give uniq ids http://jsbin.com/qajaqi/1/edit?html,css,output this exapmle solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

adding this code will add 10px of space between images

```
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
```

Comment: probably a gap of (10 + 10 =) 20px